# How do I set the value of a struts param tag from freemarker

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker

I'm having trouble setting the value of a `@s.param` tags inside `@s.a` tags.

I'm using the form:

`<@s.a action="doit">
  <@s.param name="thename" value=someThing/>
</@s.a>`

It works for some parameters, but just generates a blank value for others.

I've also tried:

- `value=$someThing`
- `value=${someThing}`
- `value="someThing"`
- `value="${someThing}"`

And the various forms seem to work in some cases, but not in others and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Referring to the edit history: It's not jsp, but freemarker isn't available as  language for formatting the code on SO, AFAIK. Also why did you re-introduced the ``` to format a code when you only need to press the code button or to add 4 leading spaces on each row ?

Comment: No, freemarker isn't available as a language, which is why I didn't use any language tag at all. It's more wrong to say it's a language that it's not than not use a tag at all. And as for the ```, I could ask you "why use 4 leading spaces on each row, when you only need to surround the code with three backticks?" They're just two different ways of signifying code formatting and that's what I prefer.

Comment: The jsp formatting tag wasn't visible, but the resulting colouring was, and the effect was better than everything black on silver, IMHO, but in the end... who cares. If you prefer the backtick (that would not trigger *any* formatting, so you can use it only when you can't - or don't want - to get colouring, like in this case), however, one is enough.

Comment: It's not about the tag being visible. I just think it's wrong to try to parse and colorize the code as jsp when it's not. It doesn't even look like jsp is really supported. Google's prettify library doesn't support jsp, and the tag page for jsp just says it uses the "default" formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be experiencing an interaction between 3 different gotchas between freemarker and struts:

- Expressions being evaluated by freemarker vs struts
- Local freemarker variables vs. properties on your `Action` class
- `String` vs non-`String` variables (`Long` for example)

**First**, the `value` attribute on the struts `param` tag is actually evaluated by struts. This means if you use the form `value="someThing"`, freemarker will just pass on `"someThing"` to struts. Struts will then evaluate that string and try to look for `getSomeThing()` on your action.

If you use the form `value=someThing`, then *freemarker* will evaluate `someThing`. If your action has a `getSomeThing()` method which returns `"anotherThing"`, then it will send `"anotherThing"` to struts. And struts will evaluate that string and try to look for `getAnotherThing()` on your action, and probably fail. You may say, "Okay, I'll just never let freemarker evaluate the strings I give to `value`, and always let struts do the evaluating." However:

**Second**, any variable you create locally in freemarker is not visible to struts. So if `someThing` is not a property on your action, and was instead created by freemarker while evaluating the template (say a loop variable), then struts won't be able to see it and will probably fail if you use the form `value="someThing"`.

**Third**, confusing the matter even more, numeric types (and possibly others) work just fine when evaluated in freemarker and passed to struts, while strings don't (as we saw in the first gotcha). So while the following will work if `someThing` is a numeric type:

`<@s.a action="doit">
  <@s.param name="thename" value=someThing/>
</@s.a>`

And you'll get a url like `/doit.action?thename=1234`, it won't work if `someThing` is a string, since struts will try to evaluate whatever `someThing` evaluates to.

### Conclusion

So what form should you use to ensure that all types (`String`s and numerics), and locally defined and action based variables work with `@s.param`? It seems like you have to always force evaluation in freemarker, and then pass the result as a string literal to struts. And the way to do that is either:

`<@s.a action="doit">
  <@s.param name="thename" value="'${someThing}'"/>
</@s.a>`

Or:

`<@s.a action="doit">
  <@s.param name="thename">${someThing}</@s.param>
</@s.a>`

Just beware that this means the variables will be formatted by freemarker and you'll probably need stuff like `?c` for numeric types to make sure you don't get commas in them.